# Video thumbnails in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, video, thumbnails

I have 16.04 + Unity. Nautilus does not show video thumbnails for me. Is it the default behaviour of Nautilus ? Any option to enable thumbnails for videos ? Thanks.

Comment: Is the question still up ?

Comment: have you checked the Nautilus settings?

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific Nautilus/Files setting on that.

[image]